# SELECT in INSERTING in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have two table Documents and RegCard (name uses a name of current_user)

Table Documents

```
CREATE TABLE public.document_dimauser
(
  documentid uuid NOT NULL,
  documentname character varying(100),
  author character varying(100),
  contents bytea,
  CONSTRAINT document_dimauser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (documentid)
)
```

Table RegCard

```
CREATE TABLE public.regcard_dimauser
(
  regcardid uuid NOT NULL,
  documentid uuid,
  documentintronumber character varying(100),
  documentexternnumber character varying(100),
  dateintro date,
  dateextern date,
  CONSTRAINT regcard_dimauser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (regcardid),
  CONSTRAINT regcard_dimauser_documentid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (documentid)
      REFERENCES public.document_dimauser (documentid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

This two tables are connected one row 'documentid'

Also, i have a function, which inserting data in this two tables. Here i try selecting last rec of documentid from first table and transer him in second table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.addrecuserdocuments(
    documentname character varying,
    contents bytea,
    documentintronumber character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
comm VARCHAR;
nameuser VARCHAR;
currdate DATE;
iddoc uuid;
BEGIN
SELECT CURRENT_USER INTO STRICT nameuser;
SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO STRICT currdate;
comm:='INSERT INTO Document_'||nameuser||' VALUES ('||quote_literal(uuid_generate_v4())||', '||quote_literal(documentname)||','||quote_literal(nameuser)||','||quote_literal(contents)||');
SELECT documentid INTO STRICT '||quote_literal(iddoc)||' FROM Document_'||nameuser||' order by documentid DESC LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO Regcard_'||nameuser||' (regcardid, documentid, documentintronumber, dateintro) VALUES ('||quote_literal(uuid_generate_v4())||' , '||quote_literal(iddoc)||',  '||quote_literal(documentintronumber)||', '||quote_literal(currdate)||');';
EXECUTE comm;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

But i have a error

```
ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
SQL-состояние: 22004
Контекст: PL/pgSQL function addrecuserdocuments(character varying,bytea,character varying) line 13 at EXECUTE
```

Please, tell me, what i do wrong?

Comment: you concat with `||` operator - if any value is null the whole string is null

Comment: Unrelated: there is no need for the `nameuser` or `currdate` variables. You can use those functions in your `INSERT` statement directly.

Comment: You shouldn't be appending the user name to  the table name. You already store the username in the table, why complicate things by using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Using of dynamic SQL is important part of my task

Comment: But dynamic SQL is the wrong choice here. This **is** a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

you concat with || operator - if any value is `null` the whole string is `null`...
you can instead do smth like :

```
comm := format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES(%L)',concat(Document_',nameuser),uuid_generate_v4());
```

and so on...

Comment: I forget say something: before i write this SELECT documentid INTO STRICT '||quote_literal(iddoc)||' FROM Document_'||nameuser||' order by documentid DESC LIMIT 1; all working. Problem is this line

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate input values if you don't need that, [use parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the string and use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to build it. You also don't need variables to store the results of built-in functions and you don't need to "select" the UUID you generated inside your code.

Putting all that together you can simplify your code to:

```
BEGIN
  iddoc := uuid_generate_v4();

  comm : = format('INSERT INTO Document_%s VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)', current_user);

  execute comm 
     using iddoc, documentname, current_user, contents;

  comm := format('insert into regcard_%s (regcardid, documentid, documentintronumber, dateintro) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)', current_user);

  execute comm
    using uuid_generate_v4(), iddoc, documentintronumber, current_date;

END;
```

This not only makes the code much more readable it is also a way to prevent SQL injection through that function.

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: I find a design that uses a table with the user name appended highly questionable - especially if that user name is *also* stored inside the table. If you don't do that you can avoid all that dynamic SQL.</sup>